# How to release docker image with Jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, release

I have a project to build a docker image, in my case it's a extension of mongo image which contains (inside the container) data. And I use this mongo docker image for integration tests purpose.

At the moment, Maven is not used to build the project. When I want to release a version of this image, I do it on my computer which is not ideal.

I would like to kept a file which contains my current version of my docker image (like pom.xml).

What should I do, add a pom.xml in my project for versionning and maven-release-plugin, add a simple version.txt which I update with during my release process ?

Or is there a like "docker.version" file I do not know to do this ?

I post an example of my project on GitHub : https://github.com/Ameausoone/mongodb-docker-with-data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First thing is to have a specific repo for each project that you have**. This helps not to mess up the docker images while pushing it to the repository.

You can use the shell scripts/commands in the pipeline script to execute all the commands which are mentioned here.

There are multiple ways in which you push the docker images to the repository.

> **Tagging based on Time and Build Number:**

Take an example of auth-api, where we create an env variable called $DOCKER_TAG in the jenkins and set it to the time the build is created:

```
DOCKER_TAG: $(date +%Y%m%d).$BUILD_NUMBER
```

$BUILD_NUMBER is provided as part of Jenkins job. Now tag the docker image as follows:

```
docker tag DOCKER_IMAGE auth-api/<DOCKER_IMAGE>:<DOCKER_TAG>
```

(Assuming you have built the docker image and push it to the repository after tagging- above step.)

**NOTE : Docker allows to push the image only if it matches the REPO-NAME)**

It helps to find out the docker image creation date and time along with the build number. This image can be deployed to different environments like dev, test, prod.

> **Tagging based on the environment**

Tag the docker image based on the deployment environment, i.e dev, test, prod.
Configure an environment variable in the pipeline script, using `withenv`, which may look something like this:

```
docker tag DOCKER_IMAGE auth-api/<DOCKER_IMAGE>:$ENV
```

This will help to have a deployment specific docker images.

You can even tag the docker image based on git commit.[not tested personally]

Comment: I was too "Mavenize" to think to use simply git tag or jenkins build number, but yes i will simply use this ! Thx